# How does the indicator probability stays stable throughout the experiment

Tags: probability

I've been dealing with this question-
An urn has 12 blue balls and 8 red balls. You extract balls one after the other. What is the expected value of the number of blue ball instances with a following red ball

This could be solved by indicators, if we define $X_i=1$ if the next ball is red for every blue ball, and say that the probability for each $X_i$ is $8/20$, we get that the expected value is $12\cdot(8/20)=4.8$, which is the correct answer.

However, I don't understand how the probability for EVERY $X_i$ stays the same. After the i'th extraction there are less then 20 balls in the urn, and the number of red balls might also differ, so why can we assume that probability is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the experiment as permutations of balls. The one in place #1 is taken first, the one in place #2 taken second, and so on. $X_i$ considers only place #i and due to symmetry, it is as likely to put a red ball in each place.

You are correct that as the experiment unfolds and you learn what happened, the probability changes. But we compute probabilities and expectations before the experiment starts.

Another intuitive approach: there is less probability for the 5th ball to be red if we've taken out many red balls already. BUT if we've taken out many blue balls - there is more probability for the 5th ball to be red. You can actually compute these probabilities and see how it balances out.